# Initialize input text field value using $rootScope in Angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have defined $rootScope variable by using following code:

```
$rootScope.userDetails = function () {
        $http.post($account + '/feedbackdiv')
            .success(function (res) {
                $rootScope.userData = res.userData;
            });
    };
    $rootScope.userDetails();
```

Now, userData is accessible from everywhere. Now I tried to assign the userData.FirstName value to text field like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control museo_sans300" id="fName" 
  placeholder="First Name" name="fName" minlength="1" ng-model="fName" 
  ng-init="fName = userData.FirstName" required="required">
```

But this didn't initial value in the text field. I also checked that when I give static value to ng-init it works correctly, like, `ng-init ="fName = 'test'"` Furthermore I also verified that I am getting value of `userData.FirstName`. Please provide a solution to initialize this input text field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reference between `fName` and `userData.FirstName` after initial assignment `fName = userData.FirstName`. Also `ngInit` is not going to be run again on every digest loop. So when later `userData.FirstName` is populated primitive `fName` is not going to be updated. This is expected javacript behavior not related to Angular.

So you either use `userData.FirstName` directly as model:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control museo_sans300" 
       id="fName" placeholder="First Name" name="fName" minlength="1" 
       ng-model="userData.FirstName" 
       required="required">
```

Or you will need to manually set `fName` in controller once `userData` is loaded.

Comment: if I bind it directly as the model, the changes also effects the $rootScope value, which is not desirable.

Comment: When I tried to manually set value of `$scope.fName = $rootScope.userData.FirstName;` in Controller, it gives undefined value.

Comment: You need to set in when it's available, in http success callback. Or you need watcher.

Comment: Variant 1: http://plnkr.co/edit/EE1PwLdskuV7hmiJTZ1V?p=preview or watch http://plnkr.co/edit/BsaIUrBdHKHKJUhUjQRd?p=preview

Comment: I have tried Variant 1 and it works great for me. Thanks. But I will also try watcher variant because I think it will be more flexible.